# Java error - Cannot Resolve symbol in Maven Project

Tags: java, string, maven, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I was working on a java project in intelliJ and all of a sudden after i restarted the project i saw error related to Cannot Resolve symbol over every line in .class files.

I tried to invalidate the cache and restart, Reimport project but nothing is happening. Please help

[image]

Comment: None of the java projects are working, im seeing the same problem in every java project. the exception is caused by 'java.lang.string'

Comment: Does the project build on plain command line? If so restart IDEA and invalidate cache...

Comment: mvn clean, mvn install, invalidate & restart - This worked. 
But why does this happen ? I had used a plugin to generate a testNG.xml file i removed it and it worked for a few seconds and all the errors can back again (before mvn clean, install and invalidate&restart).

Comment: The install is not needed only `mvn clean package` or maybe `mvn clean verify`. The problem is related to some issues in IDEA IntelliJ ...Why using a plugin to generate a testNG.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Inputs are missing.
Can you please provide a look into your Imports and Dependencies if you use any.

Edit: Make sure you are on Java 8 or higher since the Issue can occure in lower Versions